# Devise limit one session per user at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

My app is using Rails 3.0.4 and Devise 1.1.7.

I'm looking for a way to prevent users from sharing accounts as the app is a subscription based service.  I've been searching for over a week, and I still don't know how to implement a solution.  I'm hoping someone has implemented a solution and can point me in the right direction.

**Solution** (Thank you everyone for your answers and insight!)

In application controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_concurrent_session

def check_concurrent_session
  if is_already_logged_in?
    sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
  end
end

def is_already_logged_in?
  current_user && !(session[:token] == current_user.login_token)
end
```

In session_controller that overrides Devise Sessions controller:

```
skip_before_filter :check_concurrent_session

def create
  super
  set_login_token
end

private
def set_login_token
  token = Devise.friendly_token
  session[:token] = token
  current_user.login_token = token
  current_user.save
end
```

In migration AddLoginTokenToUsers

```
def self.up
  change_table "users" do |t|
    t.string "login_token"
  end
end

def self.down
  change_table "users" do |t|
    t.remove "login_token"
  end
end
```

Comment: This was working great on dev and staging, but on production it made my login process always lead to an immediate sign out. I'm always redirecting users after sign-in to the last page they were at during their previous session. Any ideas? What's weird is that my staging and production envs are identical Heroku rails 3.2/PostgreSQL stacks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do it.

- You can control IP addresses of user, so you can prevent presence of user from two IP at a time. ANd you can bind login and IP. You can try to check cities and other geolocation data through IP to block user.
- You can set cookies to control something else.

But none of this will guarantee that only one user uses this login, and that those 105 IP from all over the world doesn't belong to only one unique user, which uses Proxy or whatever.

And the last: you never need this in the Internet.

**UPD**

> However, what I'm asking is about limiting multiple users from using the same account simultaneously which I feel should be possible

So you can store some token, that will contain some encrypted data: IP + secret string + user agent + user browser version + user OS + any other personal info: `encrypt(IP + "some secret string" + request.user_agent + ...)`. And then you can set a session or cookie with that token. And with each request you can fetch it: if user is the same? Is he using the same browser and the same browser version from the same OS etc.

Also you can use dynamic tokens: you change token each request, so only one user could use system per session, because each request token will be changed, another user will be logged out as far as his token will be expired.

Comment: Sharing the account I agree is impossible to stop.  However, what I'm asking is about limiting multiple users from using the same account simultaneously which I feel should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your update fl00rs.  I'm using a simple token for now until I get it working, but I appreciate your detailed response.

Comment: You never can't do it == You can do it. Double negation here.

Comment: @KennyMeyer not only that, it means that it's impossible to not be able to do it :)

Comment: I wonder if you still have the same opinion about this now @fl00r ?

Comment: @KennyMeyer yes. There are workarounds which are suitable in many cases, but in general, you can't guarantee access for only one real person under one account.

Answer (score 37):

This gem works well: https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security

Add to Gemfile

```
gem 'devise-security'
```

after bundle install

```
rails generate devise_security:install
```

Then run

```
rails g migration AddSessionLimitableToUsers unique_session_id
```

Edit the migration file

```
class AddSessionLimitableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :unique_session_id, :string, limit: 20
  end
end
```

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Edit your app/models/user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :session_limitable # other devise options
  ... rest of file ...
end
```

Done. Now logging in from another browser will kill any previous sessions. The gem actual notifies the user that he is about to kill a current session before logging in.

Comment: It looks like it has that feature, but as of when I wrote this, it isn't compatible with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0

Comment: Works for me on Rails 4.2 && ruby 2.2.0

Comment: Works on Rails 5.0.2 and Ruby 2.3.4. 
I want to refresh the previous login page after a new login, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @TahaRushain You would not use `session_limitable` gem to refresh a previous session. Can you elaborate why you would want to refresh a previous session if one is accessing a site from a new browser? More detail is needed to properly answer your question.

Comment: @scarver2 I think I didn't explain myself correctly, I don't want to refresh the session but the view so that as soon as a new session is created in another browser, the older browser should redirect to sign-in or root path in real-time. This type of flow would provide a better UX. Would that be possible without using ActionCable?

Comment: @TahaRushain Thank you for clarifying. A good UX is admirable. With a little help from AJAX, just poll an endpoint every _n_ minutes. If you get a 200 OK, you're still logged in. If you get a 301 or 302 Redirect, then flash a message or initiate the redirect in the old browser.

Comment: Can we manage two different sessions in multiple tabs on same browser?

Comment: how can I notify the user that he is about to kill other sessions?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved the duplicate session problem.

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "my_sessions" }
```

**my_sessions controller**

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :check_concurrent_session

  def create
    super
    set_login_token
  end

  private
  def set_login_token
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    session[:token] = token
    current_user.login_token = token
    current_user.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

**application_controller**

```
  def check_concurrent_session
    if duplicate_session?
      sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
      flash[:notice] = "Duplicate Login Detected"
    end
  end

  def duplicate_session?
    user_signed_in? && (current_user.login_token != session[:token])
  end
```

**User model**
Add a string field via a migration named `login_token`

This overrides the default Devise Session controller but inherits from it as well.  On a new session a login session token is created and stored in `login_token` on the User model.  In the application controller we call `check_concurrent_session` which signs out and redirects the `current_user` after calling the `duplicate_session?` function.

It's not the cleanest way to go about it, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as actually implementing it in Devise, add this to your User.rb model.
Something like this will log them out automatically (untested).

```
  def token_valid?
     # Use fl00rs method of setting the token
     session[:token] == cookies[:token]
  end

  ## Monkey Patch Devise methods ##
  def active_for_authentication? 
    super && token_valid?
  end 
  def inactive_message 
   token_valid? ? super : "You are sharing your account." 
  end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your response.  I'm trying to fully understand your solution combined with floors.  I didn't find active_for_authentication? but I did find active? which I believe serves the same purpose.  I'm a little lost where the cookies[:token] comes into play?  Are you just setting the token in the cookie or are you storing it in a database.  I have updated my question to reflect my current progress.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the solution in the original posting did not quite work for me.  I wanted the first user to be logged out and a log-in page presented.    Also, the `sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)` method does not seem to work the way I would expect.  Using the SessionsController override in that solution I modified it to use websockets as follows:

```
def create
  super
  force_logout
end

private
def force_logout
    logout_subscribe_address = "signout_subscribe_response_#{current_user[:id]}"
    logout_subscribe_resp = {:message => "#{logout_subscribe_address }: #{current_user[:email]} signed out."}
    WebsocketRails[:signout_subscribe].trigger(signout_subscribe_address, signout_subscribe_resp)
  end
end
```

Make sure that all web pages subscribe to the signout channel and bind it to the same `logout_subscribe_address` action.  In my application, each page also has a 'sign out' button, which signs out the client via the devise session Destroy action.  When the websocket response is triggered in the web page, it simply clicks this button - the signout logic is invoked and the first user is presented with the sign in page.

This solution also does not require the `skip_before_filter :check_concurrent_session` and the model `login_token` since it triggers the forced logout without prejudice.

For the record, the `devise_security_extension` appears to provide the functionality to do this as well.  It also puts up an appropriate alert warning the first user about what has happened (I haven't figured out how to do that yet).

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of uniq IPs used per user. Now and then, run an analysis on those IPs - sharing would be obvious if a single account has simultaneous logins from different ISPs in different countries. Note that simply having a different IP is not sufficient grounds to consider it shared - some ISPs use round-robin proxies, so each hit would necessarily be a different IP.

Comment: I'm more worried about users sharing an account within an organization than across countries. Will uniq IP solution be viable if the account being shared is by multiple people on the same network?

Comment: Possibly, unless they've got a NAT gateway, which'd make all the users appear under a single (or very few IPs).

Answer (score 0):

While you can't reliably prevent users from sharing an account, what you can do (I think) is prevent more than one user being logged on at the same time to the same account.  Not sure if this is sufficient for your business model, but it does get around a lot of the problems discussed in the other answers.  I've implemented something that is currently in beta and seems to work reasonably well - there are some notes [here](http://rubythings.blogspot.com/2010/09/licenceable.html)