# Devise - Restrict multiple sessions for same user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a subscription based app, charged on the basis of number of users added.
I want to restrict users to single session.
How to implement it. I am using devise for authentication.

Thanks..

Comment: see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7068919/49186

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a devise extension with session limit support

https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension