# ruby on rails + devise and how to make sure they are logged-in only 1 time?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In ruby on rails with devise how could one check if a user is logged-in 1 time?
Its possible to login with multiple browser with the same account.

I need every user to be able to login only 1time, is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332434/devise-restrict-multiple-sessions-for-same-user/11242622#11242622) there is a devise [plugin](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension) for this.

It has an [issue](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/issues/33) with recent versions of devise, but still, there are forks dealing with issue.

Comment: Ok there is an extension available but I just want this one feature so I look for method to code it in myself not using another extension that breaks on updates.

Comment: You can check source code of the extension. It's based on giving a unique ID for each session and that sounds ok to me. But, i will agree that the security extension is somehow outdated and the unique session problem is a little more complicated then its covered in extension (like where to redirect on multiple login attempts, how to show a warning etc).

Comment: I fixed it with a before filter checking the session token and if its not the same then logout the user overruling the devise session controller