# Devise support for multiple concurrent sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 with Devise 2.2.3 for a subscription service application. I inherited the app from another developer who is no longer available. I am new to Rails and Devise.

I want to **allow a single user (email) to have more than one session** to the same app, running concurrently. The sessions may all have the same IP address or different IP addresses, though probably different devices -- desktop, laptop, table, smart phone.

I want to treat each session independently, so the user can sign on and off one session without affecting any work in progress on another session.

**Question**: Does devise support multiple concurrent sessions normally? Do I have to customize any code or config?

When I look at the User model, I see single attributes for "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip" and "authentication_token" -- this makes me think a single User can only have one session at a time.

I've looked at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199379/devise-session-limit) and at [the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) but haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, devise allows multiple concurrent sessions for same users by default. Then, if you want restrict this behavior, you need to use some extension like: [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension)

I'm using Rails 3.2.17 with Devise 3.2.2

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to identify a user's sessions (from within or without a Rails app), as an administrative function? That is, how do I answer the questions: Who is signed in? and How many sessions does a user have?

Comment: well...if you need know current users authenticated, you can take an consideration a user's column as for example: "current_singing_ip", but not exist available information to identify how many sessions does user have. Because by default, Rails uses a CookieStore to handle sessions. What it means is that all the informations needed to identify a user's session is sent to the client and nothing is stored on the server. Look at: http://pothibo.com/2013/09/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: you can change session storage to control session_id (Look at: http://pothibo.com/2013/09/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails). Then you know how many sessions per users.