# Do I need an auth_token per session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm building a product with a website, Android app and iOS app. Like with Facebook, I want to be able to be logged in on each platform simultaneously. Through my set-up with Devise, this wouldn't work because there is only one auth_token. If I log out of one service, it logs me out of all of them because the auth_token gets set to nil.

Should I have an android_auth_token and ios_auth_token?

I understand the logic behind how I would sync with the appropriate auth_token, but I haven't seen the question answered anywhere and I think it is an important topic.

How would I handle 3 separate clients (website, Android, iOS) with Devise? It seems to make sense that I need 3 auth_tokens because each has its own session, but maybe that isn't the way the industry goes about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise support for multiple concurrent sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209932/devise-support-for-multiple-concurrent-sessions)

Comment: I don't think that handles the case of Android & iOS which you can't use cookies/sessions for. Android & iOS require auth tokens.