# Avoid multiple logins with the same username and password

Tags: ruby, authentication

In my application I have a login page and I need to prevent multiple logins from the same user (same username and password). I have used different methods like having a boolean value and updating it from true to false. But it has the drawback that whenever a user closes her browser (without logging of) the flag is not updated.

Are there any ways to achieve that by using session_id or something along those lines?

Comment: See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068919/devise-limit-one-session-per-user-at-a-time May be you can get some ideas

Comment: Thanks, But I am not using devise gem.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Devise` and enable `trackable` which will save `last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, `current_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip` into database. Then simply inherit `Devise::SessionsController` and override the action `create` to check if current IP is the same as `last_sign_in_ip` and `last_sign_in_at` is not before half an hour ago.