# User should login in only three device from one account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, spree-auth-devise

I am using spree application with devise [gem](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise)

We are not getting how we could implement user should login in only three devices at a time with the same account. Can anyone help on it? I am using **rails4** with `gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails provide different option to store the session. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

you can use below gem:-
https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

Answer (score 0):

Try controlling how many active sessions a user can have, here is a rundown using Devise: [Devise limit one session per user at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068919/devise-limit-one-session-per-user-at-a-time)