# Limiting number of simultaneous logins (sessions) with Rails and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way in Rails (preferably with Devise) to limit the number of simultaneous logins with the same login name?

Comment: Do these answers help you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068919/devise-limit-one-session-per-user-at-a-time

Comment: Bless you!  That looks like exactly what I need!